# Grafana Loki testing failing and shoingh command-line-arguments not found

Tags: go, grafana-loki

I have this below file checkpoint_test.go which is a test of Grafana Loki under pkg/ingestor package.

When i try to run  `go test checkpoint_test.go`, it showing some errors. can someone guide me to solve this issue.

```
# command-line-arguments [command-line-arguments.test]
./checkpoint_test.go:27:84: undefined: Interface
./checkpoint_test.go:28:12: undefined: mockQuerierServer
./checkpoint_test.go:46:68: undefined: Config
./checkpoint_test.go:47:20: undefined: defaultIngesterTestConfig
./checkpoint_test.go:61:41: undefined: defaultLimitsTestConfig
./checkpoint_test.go:64:22: undefined: mockStore
./checkpoint_test.go:382:38: undefined: instance
./checkpoint_test.go:384:50: undefined: instance
./checkpoint_test.go:388:20: undefined: Series
./checkpoint_test.go:551:44: undefined: Chunk
./checkpoint_test.go:64:22: too many errors
FAIL    command-line-arguments [build failed]
FAIL





package ingester


// small util for ensuring data exists as we expect
func ensureIngesterData(ctx context.Context, t *testing.T, start, end time.Time, i Interface) {
    result := mockQuerierServer{
        ctx: ctx,
    }
    err := i.Query(&logproto.QueryRequest{
        Selector: `{foo="bar"}`,
        Limit:    100,
        Start:    start,
        End:      end,
    }, &result)

    ln := int(end.Sub(start) / time.Second)
    require.NoError(t, err)
    require.Len(t, result.resps, 1)
    require.Len(t, result.resps[0].Streams, 2)
    require.Len(t, result.resps[0].Streams[0].Entries, ln)
    require.Len(t, result.resps[0].Streams[1].Entries, ln)
}

func defaultIngesterTestConfigWithWAL(t *testing.T, walDir string) Config {
    ingesterConfig := defaultIngesterTestConfig(t)
    ingesterConfig.MaxTransferRetries = 0
    ingesterConfig.WAL.Enabled = true
    ingesterConfig.WAL.Dir = walDir
    ingesterConfig.WAL.CheckpointDuration = time.Second

    return ingesterConfig
}

func TestIngesterWAL(t *testing.T) {
    walDir := t.TempDir()

    ingesterConfig := defaultIngesterTestConfigWithWAL(t, walDir)

    limits, err := validation.NewOverrides(defaultLimitsTestConfig(), nil)
    require.NoError(t, err)

    newStore := func() *mockStore {
        return &mockStore{
            chunks: map[string][]chunk.Chunk{},
        }
    }

    i, err := New(ingesterConfig, client.Config{}, newStore(), limits, runtime.DefaultTenantConfigs(), nil)
    require.NoError(t, err)
    require.Nil(t, services.StartAndAwaitRunning(context.Background(), i))
    defer services.StopAndAwaitTerminated(context.Background(), i) //nolint:errcheck

    req := logproto.PushRequest{
        Streams: []logproto.Stream{
            {
                Labels: `{foo="bar",bar="baz1"}`,
            },
            {
                Labels: `{foo="bar",bar="baz2"}`,
            },
        },
    }

    start := time.Now()
    steps := 10
    end := start.Add(time.Second * time.Duration(steps))

    for i := 0; i < steps; i++ {
        req.Streams[0].Entries = append(req.Streams[0].Entries, logproto.Entry{
            Timestamp: start.Add(time.Duration(i) * time.Second),
            Line:      fmt.Sprintf("line %d", i),
        })
        req.Streams[1].Entries = append(req.Streams[1].Entries, logproto.Entry{
            Timestamp: start.Add(time.Duration(i) * time.Second),
            Line:      fmt.Sprintf("line %d", i),
        })
    }

    ctx := user.InjectOrgID(context.Background(), "test")
    _, err = i.Push(ctx, &req)
    require.NoError(t, err)

    ensureIngesterData(ctx, t, start, end, i)

    require.Nil(t, services.StopAndAwaitTerminated(context.Background(), i))

    // ensure we haven't checkpointed yet
    expectCheckpoint(t, walDir, false, time.Second)

    // restart the ingester
    i, err = New(ingesterConfig, client.Config{}, newStore(), limits, runtime.DefaultTenantConfigs(), nil)
    require.NoError(t, err)
    defer services.StopAndAwaitTerminated(context.Background(), i) //nolint:errcheck
    require.Nil(t, services.StartAndAwaitRunning(context.Background(), i))

    // ensure we've recovered data from wal segments
    ensureIngesterData(ctx, t, start, end, i)

    // ensure we have checkpointed now
    expectCheckpoint(t, walDir, true, ingesterConfig.WAL.CheckpointDuration*5) // give a bit of buffer

    require.Nil(t, services.StopAndAwaitTerminated(context.Background(), i))

    // restart the ingester
    i, err = New(ingesterConfig, client.Config{}, newStore(), limits, runtime.DefaultTenantConfigs(), nil)
    require.NoError(t, err)
    defer services.StopAndAwaitTerminated(context.Background(), i) //nolint:errcheck
    require.Nil(t, services.StartAndAwaitRunning(context.Background(), i))

    // ensure we've recovered data from checkpoint+wal segments
    ensureIngesterData(ctx, t, start, end, i)
}
```